# New to PhP and ACF (3 days in), cant get <a> to stay open

Tags: php, html, wordpress, tags, advanced-custom-fields

I am trying to have an ACF template which detects if the url is filled, when its filled it should turn the whole container into a link.

It looks like the  tag is closed automatically (even though I dont specify this).
I am trying to keep the  tag open until after the  from the '.container-fluid'.

```
<section class="imageBlock">
            <?php $url = get_sub_field('url');
                if($url != null):?>
                <a href="<?php $url;?>">
                <?php endif;?>
                    <div class="container-fluid">
                            <div class="row align-items-center">
                                <div class="col-6">
                                    <h2><?php the_sub_field('title'); ?></h2>
                                    <p><?php the_sub_field('l_txt');?></p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-6">
                                    <?php $image = get_sub_field('r_img');?>
                                    <img src="<?php echo $image['url'];?>"/>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                    </div>
                <?php if($url != null):?>
                    </a>
                <?php endif;?>

            </section>
```

Comment: _"It looks like the tag is closed automatically"_ - meaning what, exactly? And what does the actual HTML this creates look like?

Comment: When I use the browser inspector I can see that the tag closes </a> at the same line as I open it, which is not what I want, I want it to remain open until I decide to close it (according to the if statement near the end)

Comment: Can we see what it outputs?